# Replace the first occurrence of a column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the following DataFrame, and I want to replace the first occurrence of the value 2 in each column with a value of 4.  Note, the remaining 2's in the column can stay.

```
5  2  9  10  9
2  9  2   5  3
2  9  2   2  0
2  1  1   2  2
```

I have tried using `argmax()` and `idxmax()`, but for some reason all the values of 2 get replaced.  I only want the first occurrence replaced -- so that the output looks like the below:

```
5  4  9  10  9
4  9  4   5  3
2  9  2   4  0
2  1  1   2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = [[5, 2, 9, 10, 9], [2, 9, 2, 5, 3], [2, 9, 2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 1, 2, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df

```
   0  1  2   3  4
0  5  2  9  10  9
1  2  9  2   5  3
2  2  9  2   2  0
3  2  1  1   2  2
```

make condition & use `mask`

```
cond = df.eq(2) & df.eq(2).cumsum().eq(1)
out = df.mask(cond, 4).values.tolist()
```

out:

```
[[5, 4, 9, 10, 9], 
 [4, 9, 4, 5, 3], 
 [2, 9, 2, 4, 0], 
 [2, 1, 1, 2, 4]]
```