# Replace the last occurrence of a value in a column of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the following DataFrame:

```
data1 = [[2,5,6,3,1],
         [2,2,5,4,2],
         [0,1,2,2,3],
         [6,2,1,0,9],
         [2,3,4,1,2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(df)
```

I need to replace only the last occurrence of the value 2 in each column with the value 7.  Note the replacement is ONLY for the last '2', the proceeding '2's in the column should remain in place.
The desired result being:

```
[[2,5,6,3,1],
 [2,2,5,4,2],
 [0,1,7,7,3],
 [6,7,1,0,9],
 [7,3,4,1,7]]
```

I tried to use `last_valid_index()`, as well as `diff()`, and did not get the results I was looking for.
Like the following:

```
cond = df.eq(2) & df.last_valid_index()==2
out = df.mask(cond, 7)
print(out)
```

I have tried various versions of this, as well as with `diff()`, and I cannot seem to get the desired result (as shown above).  Any advice will be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. What dataframe library are you using? Please [edit] to add the tag for it. If you're using Pandas, what you're showing here is not a dataframe, so please make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341) -- probably as simple as `print(df)`.

Comment: Yes, I am using Pandas, but I will use another library if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
m = df.eq(2).replace(False, np.nan).bfill()
print(df.mask(m ^ m.shift(-1), 7))
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     2     5     6     3     1
1     2     2     5     4     2
2     0     1     7     7     3
3     6     7     1     0     9
4     7     3     4     1     7
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     2     5     6     3     1
1     2     2     5     4     2
2     0     1     2     2     3
3     6     2     1     0     9
4     2     3     4     1     2
```

Explanation:

```
m = df.eq(2).replace(False, np.nan).bfill()
print(m)

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0  True  True  True  True  True
1  True  True  True  True  True
2  True  True  True  True  True
3  True  True   NaN   NaN  True
4  True   NaN   NaN   NaN  True

print(m.shift(-1))

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0  True  True  True  True  True
1  True  True  True  True  True
2  True  True   NaN   NaN  True
3  True   NaN   NaN   NaN  True
4   NaN  None  None  None   NaN

# The ^ (XOR) operation is True if there is only one value True

print(m ^ m.shift(-1))

    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False   True   True  False
3  False   True  False  False  False
4   True  False  False  False   True

# .mask() sets the True values to 7
```

---

Another version:

```py
tmp = (df == 2)[::-1].idxmax()

for c, v in zip(tmp.index, tmp):
    df.loc[v, c] = 7

print(df)
```

Comment: How does this work? Please add an explanation

Comment: @wjandrea I've added a little explanation

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

make condition by reverse row dataframe (`df.iloc[::-1]`)

then, you can use [the code I provided before.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77903520/20430449)

```
cond = df.iloc[::-1].eq(2) & df.iloc[::-1].eq(2).cumsum().eq(1)
out = df.mask(cond, 7)
```

out:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   2   5   6   3   1
1   2   2   5   4   2
2   0   1   7   7   3
3   6   7   1   0   9
4   7   3   4   1   7
```

Comment: I'd rather write `m = df.loc[::-1].eq(2) ; df[m&m.cumsum().eq(1)] = 7` ;)

Answer (score 1):

With `.eq(2)`, you can use [`.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get the *first* occurrence, so you just need to flip the dataframe for that to work.

Now you have a vector of indexes, but dataframes don't support indexing along an axis, however, NumPy arrays do, so you could index into the array backing the dataframe via [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html). One thing though: if your dataframe has a non-default index, you'll need to drop it.

```
indexes = df.reset_index(drop=True)[::-1].eq(2).idxmax()
df.values[indexes, range(df.shape[1])] = 7
df
```

Result:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  2  5  6  3  1
1  2  2  5  4  2
2  0  1  7  7  3
3  6  7  1  0  9
4  7  3  4  1  7
```

**Edit**: Apparently `.iloc` actually does support indexing along an axis, but **only for setting**, and I can't find where that's documented. So this works, but I would be cautious using it:

```
df.iloc[indexes, range(df.shape[1])] = 7
```

For getting, you get the normal behaviour, confusingly:

```
>>> df.iloc[indexes, range(df.shape[1])]
   0  1  2  3  4
4  2  3  4  1  2
3  6  2  1  0  9
2  0  1  2  2  3
2  0  1  2  2  3
4  2  3  4  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Rank or fillna are options:

```
df.mask(df.iloc[::-1].ne(2).rank(method='first').eq(1) & df.eq(2),7)
```

or

```
df.iloc[::-1].mask(df.eq(2)).fillna(7,limit=1).fillna(2).iloc[::-1]
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  2  5  6  3  1
1  2  2  5  4  2
2  0  1  7  7  3
3  6  7  1  0  9
4  7  3  4  1  7
```

Comment: This  is soooooo helpful!! Thank you!